# Serverless framework with python not importing custom modules

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Hi I am using the serverless framework to deploy my ML model.
I structured my repo like below:

```
services
|
|
 fun1
 |
  mysubpackage
  |
   my_submodule.py
  requirements.txt
  handler.py
  myfun.yml
serverless.yml
```

My serverless.yml is written in [this way](https://pastebin.com/H02u67nJ) here  [myfun.yml](https://pastebin.com/qEzrw16m)

However I am always getting the error my_submodule not found. Am I setting up anything wrong? thanks.